# CasperJS senxAjax not working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a script from example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var data, wsurl = 'http://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos';

casper.start('http://github.com/', function() {
    data = this.evaluate(function(wsurl) {
        return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, 'GET', null, false));
    }, {wsurl: wsurl});
});

casper.then(function() {
    require('utils').dump(data);
});

casper.run();
```

When i run in my console: 
`$ casperjs api.js --web-security=no`

I'm getting `null`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `https`on `wsurl`,It worked for me.

```
var wsurl = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos';

casper.start('http://github.com/', function() {
    data = this.evaluate(function(wsurl) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, 'GET', null, false));
        } catch (e) {
            __utils__.echo(e);
        }

    }, {wsurl: wsurl});
});
```

Comment: i'm got Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Comment: Did you forget to add --web-security=no. It is normally related to cross domain xhr requests

Comment: yes, i'm add this. when i add --ssl-protocol=any all ok.